# batch file to run office build in uninstaller

Tags: batch-file, command, line

I am writing a batch script which I am having trouble with.
First, it checks for Admin permissions.
Second, it checks to see what version of Microsoft office is installed on the system.
Third, it goes to the build in unstabler.

The problem is with the third part. I get admin right. I can find what version of office is installed, setting it in `%office-version%`. But I can't check the %office_version% correctly in my `if` statements. Here is my code:

```
@echo Off

::----------------------------------------------
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
::------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: This part of the cod4e found what office is install on the computer 
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%O in ('ftype ^|findstr /r /I "\\OFFICE[0-9]*" 2^>nul') do (
    set "verp=%%~O"
    goto :end_for
)
:end_for

for %%P in (%verp%) do (
    set "off_path=%%~dpP"
    for %%V in ("!off_path:~0,-1!") do (

     set "office_version=%%~nV"
     goto :end_for2
    )
)
:end_for2
echo %office_version%
Pause
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
:: That the var of %Offfice_Verson% then  running the  build in remove of that office software.
::-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if %office_version%== office12 goto 2007
        If %office_version%== office14 goto 2010
        If %office_version%== office15 goto 2013

            :2007
            Echo Unstailling office 2007
            cd "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\Office Setup Controller"
            Goto remove

            :2010
            Echo Unstailling office 2010
            cd "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\Office Setup Controller"
            Goto remove

            :2013
            Echo Unstailling 2013
            cd "%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\Office Setup Controller"
            Goto Remove

            :Remove
                %homedrive%
                SETUP.EXE
                Echo Done!!!!!
                Pause
                Exit
```

So any help you can send me will be a great help. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your `if` statements:

```
If %office_version%== office12 goto 2007
```

The space after `==` is the problem. You are checking if the string outputted by `%office_version%` is literally equal to " office12" including the space character.

```
If "%office_version%"=="office12" goto :2007
```

You should probably also have something after the if statements, in case none of your if conditions are met. Something like:

```
echo Unable to identify Office version
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight on the string